# Extend range thumb over relative positioned div

Tags: jquery, css, range, css-position, shadow-dom

I'm editing the CSS for the shadow DOM elements of an `input[type=range]`, and I want to extend the slider thumb to cover the div below, and to do this, I have to set the `position` of the thumb as `fixed`. The problem is that in the div below that has to go below the thumb I have some divs that have `position: relative` (and cannot be positioned differently), which somehow put them in foreground, covering the thumb.

This is the code. However I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/x4Umt/) to explain better my problem.

### HTML

```
<input type="range" id="slider" />
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: red;
    height: 30px;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 85px;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 120px;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
}

#left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    background: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background: yellow;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Basically, I want the black bar to cover the yellow div, without removing the `position: relative` property from that div. Is that possible?

Comment: use z-indexes on your positioned elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `z-index` to change the natural stacking order of elements positioned anything other than `static`.

So I added a value of 1 for the `z-index` here:

```
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 85px;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/x4Umt/1/).

Comment: Mmmh. I swear I tried to give a z-index to the thumb and it didn't work. I must have changed something else since... Anyway, thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Setting the position to relative worked for me.

Starting css with problem

```
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #004687;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -0.2px;
  z-index:5;
}
```

Ending css:

```
        input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
      border: 0px solid #000000;
      height: 30px;
      width: 15px;
      border-radius: 0px;
      background: #004687;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin-top: -0.2px;
      z-index:5;

  position:relative;
}
```